# How to place a field in bootstrap 4 card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a code from somewhere to place in my bootstrap 4 card

```
.byline {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9F9F9F;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 4rem;
  margin: 1rem -4rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: calc(100% + 8rem);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

[byline class go outside the card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg2Jc.png)

But it not fixes properly.

I used normal bootstrap code like

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="card-columns">
        {% for post in paginator.posts %}

          <li>

              <div class="card">
                 {% if post.youtubeId and post.youtubeId != "" %}
                 {% include youtubeplayer.html id=post.youtubeId %}
                 {% endif %}
                 {% if page.image.feature and page.image.feature != "" %}
                 <img src="{{ page.image.feature }}" alt="{{ post.title }}" class="card-img-top">
                 {% endif %}
                 <div class="card-body">
<div class="byline"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{post.date | date: '%Y, %b %d'}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{post.author}}</span></div>
                   <h5 class="card-title"><a class="post-link text-black" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
                   <p class="card-text">{{ post.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords:25 }}</p>
                   <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="btn btn-danger text-white" role="button">Read More</a>
                 </div>

               </div>

           </li>

            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div
```

Please help me to align correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Your element's width is exceeding the full width of the parent and thus overflowing. I'd suggest to keep it at 100%.

Comment: Now it look like https://s17.postimg.org/662i9trcv/Screenshot_from_2018-02-08_13-21-18.png

Comment: Post all of the relevant code. Not just the CSS for one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
.byline {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9F9F9F;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 1rem -0.75rem 1rem -1.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: calc(100% + 2.5rem);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width to 100% only (instead of doing that calculation) and remove the margin, see if that works.

The css class should look something like this afterwards:

```
.byline {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9F9F9F;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 4rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
}
```